# I want to get text from anchor tag using selenium python I want print text helloworld

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
<div class="someclass">
<p class="name"><a href="#/word/1/">helloworld</a></p>
</div>
```

//I want to print helloworld text from anchor tag, using python selenium code.

Comment: What you have tried ? are you seeing any thing which is complex to you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using CSS:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector("p.name a")`,
```

or you can do it using xpath:

```
.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='name']/a")
```

Example:

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("p.name a")
print element.get_attribute("text")
```

I hope this helped, if not tell me :)

Comment: `.text` doesn't return text value for anchor tag. this one does `element.get_attribute("text")`

Answer (score 1):

**One step solution:**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="name"]/a').get_attribute('text')
```

The gives you the text of anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from any html tag using Selenium in python,
You can simply use ".get_attribute('text')".
In this case:

```
a_tag = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.name a")
a_tag.get_attribute('text')
```